# Google Play Store rejects updates for Android apps due to broken functionality policy violations

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

The Google Play Team, has rejected the app to upload on the Google Play Store on the basis of  **Broken Functionality policy** without mentioning the **error stack trace**, **screenshot/video** and also does not highlighted the android device's properties **(manufacturer, android-version)**.

The Google Play Team, mention the following violation description in the email:

Your app contains content that isn’t compliant with the Broken Functionality policy.

> **App loads, but crashes**

We don't allow apps that crash, force close, freeze, or otherwise function abnormally. Below are a few examples of common violations:

> **Apps that don't install**

> **Apps that install, but don't load**

> **Apps that load, but are not responsive**

I have appealed to Google Play Developer team to upload and approve the android app release, mentioned as the same app version/release is working fine on my physical android device (Infinix-X687, Android-10). In response of the appeal they only mention the following description:

> **For example, your app  loads, but crashes.**

Comment: It is not clear what kind of answer you are looking for. Some tips: [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Please, [contact Google Play Console support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp) for that type of issues.